# How Can I find neighbors positions of 2d array using depth first search

Tags: depth-first-search, adjacency-matrix

> I just need to find neighbors positions of  2d array using depth first search.
> for example assume below one is the 2D array.
>
> {{0,0,0,0,0,},
> {0,1,1,1,0,},
> {0,1,1,1,0,},
> {0,1,1,1,0,},
> {0,0,0,1,1,},};
>
> print position x and y neighbors positions with value 1 using **dfd(x,y)** eg: dfd(2,2) so  neighbors positions are (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3).
>
> So this is the code I have tried in java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        dfs(1,1);



    }

    static int N = 5;
    static int M = 5;

    static boolean[][] vis = new boolean[1001][1001];
    static int[][] arr ={{0,0,0,0,0,},
                        {0,1,0,1,0,},
                        {0,1,1,1,0,},
                        {0,1,0,0,0,},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,},};




    public static boolean isValid(int x,int y){
        if(x<=0 || x>N || y<=0 || y>M){
            return false;
        }

        if(vis[x][y] == true){
            return false;
        }



        return true;
    }



    static void dfs(int x,int y){
        int[] dx = {-1,0,1,0};
        int[] dy = {0,1,0,-1};

        vis[x][y] = true;
        System.out.println("row: "+x+" col: "+y);


        for(int i =0;i<4;i++){
            if(isValid(x+dx[i],y+dy[i])){
                dfs(x+dx[i],y+dy[i]);
            }
        }

    }


}
```